# Rails JSON unexpected token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm perplexed by the issues I'm seeing with my JSON.  I am using my controller to inject some values, read from a file from my public folder, into a fxn call.

**app/views/comparison/graphs.html.haml**:

```
  - tmp = File.readlines(txt)
  :javascript
    generate_plot(#{tmp.first})
```

which generates this in my html:

```
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    generate_plot([[[22.0,307.0,491.0,35.0,580.0,40.0,387.0,28.0,34.0,519.0,4.0,59.0,33.0,448.0,24.0,341.0],["2011-04-27T05:32:00-06:00","2011-04-27T05:32:00-06:00","2011-05-20T02:49:00-06:00","2011-05-20T02:49:00-06:00","2010-10-12T23:27:00-06:00","2010-10-12T23:27:00-06:00","2010-11-21T19:20:00-07:00","2010-11-21T19:20:00-07:00","2011-11-03T08:59:00-06:00","2011-11-03T08:59:00-06:00","2011-02-22T03:24:00-07:00","2011-02-22T03:24:00-07:00","2010-08-17T20:26:00-06:00","2010-08-17T20:26:00-06:00","2011-11-09T06:15:00-07:00","2011-11-09T06:15:00-07:00"]],[[24.0,463.0,566.0,31.0,864.0,57.0,28.0,596.0,717.0,47.0,31.0,28.0,596.0,35.0,597.0,622.0,463.0,24.0,463.0,24.0,719.0,51.0,556.0,30.0,51.0,891.0,30.0,556.0,494.0,38.0,23.0,443.0,581.0,28.0,581.0,28.0,556.0,30.0,622.0,31.0],["2010-10-15T10:04:00-06:00","2010-10-15T10:04:00-06:00","2010-09-20T04:24:00-06:00","2010-09-20T04:24:00-06:00","2010-01-08T02:10:00-07:00","2010-01-08T02:10:00-07:00","2010-09-02T20:40:00-06:00","2010-09-02T20:40:00-06:00","2010-07-08T13:11:00-06:00","2010-07-08T13:11:00-06:00","2010-02-22T23:10:00-07:00","2010-09-15T04:13:00-06:00","2010-09-15T04:13:00-06:00","2010-05-08T19:01:00-06:00","2010-05-08T19:01:00-06:00","2010-02-22T23:10:00-07:00","2010-01-10T18:59:00-07:00","2010-01-10T18:59:00-07:00","2010-06-23T14:10:00-06:00","2010-06-23T14:10:00-06:00","2010-04-04T21:57:00-06:00","2010-04-04T21:57:00-06:00","2010-01-09T11:01:00-07:00","2010-01-09T11:01:00-07:00","2010-04-30T02:10:00-06:00","2010-04-30T02:10:00-06:00","2010-10-08T13:59:00-06:00","2010-10-08T13:59:00-06:00","2010-03-03T13:12:00-07:00","2010-03-03T13:12:00-07:00","2010-06-29T15:06:00-06:00","2010-06-29T15:06:00-06:00","2010-02-14T05:47:00-07:00","2010-02-14T05:47:00-07:00","2010-06-18T05:23:00-06:00","2010-06-18T05:23:00-06:00","2010-05-12T20:05:00-06:00","2010-05-12T20:05:00-06:00","2010-03-04T19:18:00-07:00","2010-03-04T19:18:00-07:00"]],2])
  //]]>
</script>
```

I've checked and rechecked my input, but I get this error:

**Unexpected token error ,**

My Json is valid, when I simply delete the parenthesis and the function call:

http://jsfiddle.net/VVL8C/

I'm not sure what else could be going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a valid JSON example

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

> http://www.json.org/js.html

At the end instead of `,2])`  try

```
,[[2],[""]] )
```